# angular component functionality with $window

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

Whats wrong with this angular component:

https://embed.plnkr.co/yMYfWk/

My original functionality works well with directives:

https://embed.plnkr.co/4nFKnM/

I believe this has something to do with $window injection

Answer (score 0):

1. Assign the showCollapsed variable to the controller function body, not $scope: `ctrl.showCollapsed = true;`
2. rewrite the require property of the children like: `require: { nsCollapsibleHeader: '^nsCollapsibleHeader' },`
3. use the showCollapsed variable in your template like: `ng-hide="$ctrl.nsCollapsibleHeader.showCollapsed"`

Here is a [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BnMrxotAmKObT5axErUO?p=preview).